# udp port blocked across all processes (python - pi)

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, udp

I have a Raspberry PI network of controllers in a homebrew security system.  Each one launches several independent processes for different functions, and an MQTT broker ties everything together.

Each PI/process is hardcoded with the address of the MQTT broker, and I would like to instead have each one query a central server for the broker's location.

I have every process opening a UDP socket set for broadcast, and each one binds to a different listening port. On startup, it sends a query (which includes its listening port) to the central server, which sends the reply to the correct listening port.

This works fine for one process only, the others (on the same PI) all timeout without getting a response. Wireshark shows that only one of three actually sends the query to the wire, and the curious thing is that the LAST process to open the socket is the one that works. Snippet from the debug log:

```
mpi@RPI02:~ $ cat /var/log/vlab.debug.log
2020-02-28 17:08:55,242 garagectlr.31: startup
2020-02-28 17:08:55,243 root.2:
2020-02-28 17:08:55,244 root.2: startup
2020-02-28 17:08:55,250 root: looking for broker on port 10417...
2020-02-28 17:08:55,255 garagectlr: looking for broker on port 10416...
2020-02-28 17:08:57,117 sms-receiver.18:
2020-02-28 17:08:57,118 sms-receiver.18: startup
2020-02-28 17:08:57,121 sms-receiver: looking for broker on port 10419...
2020-02-28 17:08:57,124 sms-receiver: rx [mqtt-broker=192.168.99.99]
2020-02-28 17:08:57,225 sms-receiver: located broker at 192.168.99.99
2020-02-28 17:08:57,255 root: FATAL: unable to locate MQTT broker
2020-02-28 17:08:57,260 garagectlr: FATAL: unable to locate MQTT broker
2020-02-28 17:08:57,270  * Running on http://192.168.99.162:6060/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Here is the relevant python code for each PI, snipped a little:

```
    #
    # start looking for broker
    #

    # get unique listening port
    listen_port = os.getpid() + 10000
    logging.debug("%s: looking for broker on port %d..."%(self.process,listen_port))
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        sock.bind(('',listen_port))
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("%s: "%(self.process))

    tries = 0
    try:
        while self.broker == None and tries < 2:
            query = "query mqtt-broker:%s:%d"%(self.process,listen_port)
            sock.sendto(query,("192.168.99.255",1414))
            sock.settimeout(2)
            data,addr = sock.recvfrom(64)
            logging.debug("%s: rx [%s]"%(self.process,data))
            if data[0:5]=='mqtt-':
                self.broker = data[12:]
                time.sleep(.1)
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                tries = tries + 1
    except Exception:
        print('timeout')
    sock.close()        
    if self.broker == None:
        logging.debug("%s: FATAL: unable to locate MQTT broker"%(self.process))
    else:    
        logging.debug("%s: located broker at %s"%(self.process,self.broker))
        self.sendBoot()            
        self.pubTest("mqtt@%s.%s startup"%(self.process,self.version))            
        m_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.mqtt_thread)
        m_thread.start()
```

I thought that, by binding to unique ports for RX, I would not have any interference between sockets, but clearly only one is working. Why are the other two not even sending the query?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I had the WHILE loop inside the TRY-CATCH block, so that the first time the receiver timed out, the while loop was broken.

I put the TRY inside the WHILE like this:

```
    tries = 0
    query = "query mqtt-broker:%s:%d"%(self.process,listen_port)

    while self.broker == None and tries < 4:
        try:
            sock.sendto(query,("192.168.99.255",1414))
            sock.settimeout(2)
            data,addr = sock.recvfrom(64)
            if data[0:5]=='mqtt-':
                self.broker = data[12:]
                time.sleep(.1)
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                tries = tries + 1
        except Exception:
            pass    ## timeout

    try:
        sock.close()        
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("%s: "%(self.process))
```

thinking each process would have an opportunity to retry if the query failed. I'm not sure what was wrong in the first place but this works quite reliably now:

```
mpi@RPI02:~ $ cat /var/log/vlab.debug.log
2020-02-29 17:07:47,981 root.2:
2020-02-29 17:07:47,982 root.2: startup
2020-02-29 17:07:47,986 garagectlr.31: startup
2020-02-29 17:07:47,992 garagectlr: looking for broker on port 10421...
2020-02-29 17:07:48,010 root: looking for broker on port 10424...
2020-02-29 17:07:49,895 sms-receiver.18:
2020-02-29 17:07:49,896 sms-receiver.18: startup
2020-02-29 17:07:49,901 sms-receiver: looking for broker on port 10423...
2020-02-29 17:07:50,004 sms-receiver: located broker at 192.168.99.99
2020-02-29 17:07:50,048 sms-receiver:  * Running on http://192.168.99.162:6060
2020-02-29 17:07:50,098 garagectlr: located broker at 192.168.99.99
2020-02-29 17:07:50,140 root: located broker at 192.168.99.99
mpi@RPI02:~ $
```

I think it's odd that the queries are stacked, and then satisfied in reverse order. But hey, it works.